# rbx tests fail with "Requested binary installation but no rubies are available to download"

Tags: ruby, travis-ci, rubinius

I am writing a gem and I'm targeting Ruby, JRuby, and Rubinius. I'm using Travis CI to build my library. When I target Ruby and JRuby, my gem builds correctly, but when targeting Rubinius, it does not work. Here is the error:

> ```
> Using worker: worker-linux-2-2.bb.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-13   
> git.1   
> $ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git://github.com/maxgale/actor.git maxgale/actor
> Cloning into 'maxgale/actor'...
> remote: Counting objects: 74, done.
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (48/48), done.
> remote: Total 74 (delta 29), reused 64 (delta 22)
> Receiving objects: 100% (74/74), 12.06 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
> Resolving deltas: 100% (29/29), done.
> Checking connectivity... done.
>
> $ cd maxgale/actor
> git.3
> $ git checkout -qf f83f26d85f69e9c2965a4faa2065dd37ac789c36
> $ rvm use rbx --install --binary --fuzzy
> rbx is not installed - installing.
> Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
> Requested binary installation but no rubies are available to download, consider skipping --binary flag.
>
> Gemset '' does not exist, 'rvm rbx do rvm gemset create ' first, or append '--create'.
> The command "rvm use rbx --install --binary --fuzzy" failed and exited with 2 during setup.
>
> Your build has been stopped.
> ```

Here is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: ruby
cache: bundler

gemfile:
  - gemfiles/Gemfile.travis
rvm:
  - 2.0.0
  - 1.9.3
  - jruby-19mode
  - rbx
```

`gemfiles/Gemfile.travis`:

```
platforms :rbx do
  gem 'rubysl', '~> 2.0'
end

eval_gemfile File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
```

My normal `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec path: File.expand_path('../', __FILE__)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by targeting `rbx-2` instead of `rbx`. My `.travis.yml` ended up looking like this:

```
language: ruby
cache: bundler

gemfile:
  - gemfiles/Gemfile.travis
rvm:
  - 2.0.0
  - 1.9.3
  - jruby-19mode
  - rbx-2
```